# for loop and appending the set of result to div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to append every 3 records to one div in a for loop. numberList is dynamic so we are not sure of the exact length. requirement is that pick 3 records and wrap it in div. 
For example if numberList.length is 7 then we should have 3 divs. first 2 div will contain 3 records and last div will have one record.

How to go about this?

```
for (var j = 0; j < numberList.length; j++) {
number = numberList[j].Number;
}
```

after every 3 records, take the result and append in one div

Comment: So how are you getting the number list in this case? Have you tried anything yet? If yes please do not hesitate to post here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var numberList = [ 123, 234, 345, 456, 567, 678, 789 ]; // sample data

var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    div;

for (var j = 0; j < numberList.length; j++) {
    if (!(j % 3)) {
        div = document.createElement('div');
        frag.appendChild(div);
    }
    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' ' + numberList[j]));
}

document.body.appendChild(frag);
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/vtQtr/

---

Most of this should look pretty familiar; you may want to read up on the [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) `%` (sometimes called "mod" or "modulo") if you're not familiar with it.

We also use a document fragment to avoid repeatedly modifying the document. First, we insert things into the fragment, and then we insert the entire fragment into the document at once.

I separated the numbers in each div with a single space in this example, but you could adapt it to use anything you like.

Answer (score 1):

You need something this?!

```
for (var j = 0; j < numberList.length; j++) {  
  if ((j+1)%3) {  
    // create new div
  } else {
    // add record to the div
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var arr = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven"];
    var j = 0;
    var str = "";
    var master = $("#masterDiv");
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        str += arr[i];
        j++;
        if (j >= 3) {
            master.append($('<div/>', { html: str }));
            str = "";
            j = 0;
        }
    }
    master.append($('<div/>', { html: str }));

});   
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="masterDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not really relevant to the question, but I don't think this is valid XHTML (`<script>` wants PCDATA, not CDATA).

Comment: @DaggNabbit: sorry, id dont know the difference between pcdata and cdata

Comment: (Parsed) character data. If it's parsed, you need to escape certain symbols, like `<`. Most developers are moving away from XHTML these days in favor of HTML5, which uses the XML equivalent of (unparsed) CDATA in script tags (I don't think it has a name in HTML).

Answer (score 1):

-- Try This

```
var numberList = [10, 20, 30, 80, 50, 60 , 70 ,80,90,100,110,120,130];

var currentRecord = '';
var Num = 0;
var content = '';

for (var j = 0; j < numberList.length; j++) {
    content = '';
    Num = (j + 1);
    if (Num % 3 == 0) {
        currentRecord += numberList[j] + '   ';
        $('#content').append('<div> newDiv '+ currentRecord+'</div>' );
        currentRecord = '';
    }
    else {
        currentRecord += numberList[j] + '   ';
    }

    if ((Num == numberList.length) && (Num % 3 != 0)) {
         $('#content').append('<div>newDiv '+ currentRecord + '</div>' );
    }

}
```

Comment: This really doesn't improve on the answers that were already here, and includes a lot of unnecessary redundancy and some dead code... http://jsfiddle.net/vbMwh/